# Типы данных. type of?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поле:

```
<input type="text" class="callback2_hour" placeholder="00" maxlength="2"><span class="callback2_text">ч</span>
```

в js я хочу узнать тип вводимых данных:

```
$('.callback2_hour').keyup(function () {
    console.log(typeof ($(this).val()));
});
```

и при вводе чисел получаю тип string. Даже если я сделаю input type="number", все равно тип string. Вопрос: как? ) 
Я хочу выполнять разные действия для разных типов.

Comment: никак - значения инпута - это **всегда** строка.

Answer (score 1):

`Input` всегда возвращает строку, даже если вы вводите туда число, даже если вы введете туда валидный `JSON`, он не превратиться в объект.

Можете пытаться привести строку к числу и если получилось, то это число, если нет, то это строка

```
const getType = (val) => {
    let isNumber = !isNaN(+val);

    return isNumber ? "number" : "string";
}
```

Дальше можете уже попробовать разбирать строку на значения типа `boolean`, `object` (использовать регулярки для `boolean`, пытаться привести строку к объекту, через `JSON.parse` и т.д.)

**UPD**
Обновил ответ, теперь только числа возвращают `number`

Comment: спасибо. !isNaN( parseInt(val, 10) - помогло :)

Comment: `getType('123qwe')` вернет `"number"`, не уверен, что это правильно.

Comment: У меня задача сделать так, чтобы юзер не мог вводить буквы в поле. Ввод обрабатываю по событию keyup. Поэтому, если юзер введет 123q ,то parseInt('123q') вернет 123 и я тут же подменяю в поле инпут 123q на 123 :) Всё норм - задача решена )

Comment: @amijin всё что Вы сейчас описали было бы неплохо писать в самом вопросе.

Comment: А вообще,  Yaant,  вы правы. isNaN( parseInt('123qwe', 10) вернет false

Comment: @Mihanik71 не, я как раз и хотел узнать про преобразование данных и в частности про тип данных из input. Мне ответили. Меня ответы полностью устроили.

Answer (score 0):

Вы проверяете тип поля объекта DOM элемента. Всегда будете получать строку.
Можете пробовать привести к типу или по регулярке проверять является ли содержимое строки числом или строкой